# Android: How to start an activity from LazyAdapter in onClick

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a LazyAdapter that extends from BaseAsapter, in which i have implemented a clickListener. If the user click on Facebook it should open the facebook and if the user clicks on Twitter it should take to the next activity.

My Code in LazyAdapter is

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Facebook))
                {

                    SocialActivity obj1=new SocialActivity();
                    obj1.startFB(context);


                }
                else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Twitter))
                {

                    SocialActivity obj=new SocialActivity();
                    obj.startTwitter(context);  
                }

            }
        });
```

and this is the Code in `SocialActivity`

Twitter Method

```
void startTwitter(Context con)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(con,TwitterInterface.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Facebook Method

```
void startFb(Context con)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(con,FaceBook.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Instead of this I have also tried this code in `LazyAdapter`, but every time it gives me `Null Pointer Exception`. So any help to solve this problem will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Facebook))
                {
                    SocialActivity obj1=new SocialActivity();
                    Intent in = new Intent(context,Facebook.class);

                    obj1.startActivity(in);


                }
                else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Twitter))
                {

                    SocialActivity obj=new SocialActivity();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,TwitterInterface.class);

                    obj.startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Comment: can you please post you adapter whole code ?

Comment: So what is the problem? And where are you calling that function?

Comment: If you're starting the activity inside the `LazyAdapter` which mean you would be having `mContext` as well. So, try passing the `mContext` instead of `context` inside the `setOnClickListener`. the problem is with the context i guess so that you're getting `NullPointerException`

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Also post your LazyAdapter full code.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Gupta I am calling the function inside `onClickListener` which is inside `getView`

Comment: Can you show me that adapter class full code

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by using

```
v.getContext().startActivity(intent)

Intent intent = new Intent(context,TwitterInterface.class);

v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you don't need to take the `context` inside the `SocialActivity` as you're calling from inside `getView()`. Better you would pass the `context` from `getView()` which would be more OOPS way of programming

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's more simple and a good practice of coding

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Facebook))
            {
                SocialActivity obj1=new SocialActivity();
                obj1.startFB(mContext);
            }
            else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Twitter))
            {
                SocialActivity obj=new SocialActivity();
                obj.startTwitter(mContext);  
            }

        }
    });
```